# Integrate P24 payments in Prestashop Stripe Module

Tags: stripe-payments, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

Just as the title states I need to enable P24 payments through Stripe official module for Prestashop. How can I implement this feature in the module?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that's not currently possible, but you could reach out to Stripe Support for confirmation/to request the feature: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email

Comment: I already reached out, but they said that they are not the one who develops it. When I turned to the right company, they didnt provide any support at all.